# Скрыть компонент из toolbar

Tags: java, android, android-toolbar, actionbar

Как программно можно скрыть один из `MenuItem` на `toolbar`?

Comment: action это вьюха? если да, то action.setVisibility(View.GONE)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**main_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    ...

    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_action_share"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_share_white_24dp"
        android:visible="true" //показать изначально    
        android:title="Share"
        app:showAsAction="always"/>

</menu>
```

**Activity.java**

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    MenuItem shareItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_action_share);
    if (что-то) shareItem.setVisible(false); //скрыть программно
    return true;
}
```

---

Если Вы хотите контролировать меню из фрагмента, то нужно вызвать [setHasOptionsMenu](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#setHasOptionsMenu(boolean)) в `onCreate()` фрагмента.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}
```

Затем переопределить `onCreateOptionsMenu`

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);
    menu.clear();//например убрать все элементы меню.
    return true;
}
```

Comment: А как сделать чтобы не при создании меню, а при смене фрагмента?

Comment: Вылезает "Method does not override method from its superclass" на @Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater)

Comment: @Arina вот так будет вернее, обновил ответ.

Comment: та же самая ошибка